# Как получить меню в wordpress через rest api?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, api

Здравствуйте, нужно вывести меню в приложении под вордпресс, связано по REST API, просмотрел документацию developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/ но ответа не нашел, есть еще 1 плагин, wordpress.org/plugins/wp-api-menus/ но хотелось бы 1 для всего использовать, есть ли вариант исключительно все сделать 1м офф плагином wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Меню не включены в стандартный список endpoints для Rest API. Плагин wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/ тоже не содержит такого функционала. С другой стороны, я не понимаю вообще необходимость этого плагина. Rest API в WordPress работает и без него. Перейдите, например, по такой ссылке:

http://test.kagg.eu/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/

увидите все посты на моем тестовом сайте.

Плагин wordpress.org/plugins/wp-api-menus/ можно использовать и без wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/, что я и сделал для проверки. Сейчас на тестовом сайте установлен только wordpress.org/plugins/wp-api-menus/. Перейдите по ссылке

http://test.kagg.eu/wp-json/wp-api-menus/v2/menus/

и вы увидите список меню.

Так что ответ такой: да, можно использовать один плагин, и он называется wordpress.org/plugins/wp-api-menus/