# Запрос для выборки записей WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Есть отдельный PHP файл query.php. Также есть рубрика с tag_ID=3. В рубрике есть записи. Мне необходимо в файле query.php выполнить такой запрос и получить в итоге следующие данные: Заголовок записи, Дата создания, Текст записи, Ссылка на картинку записи. Полез в БД, но там как-то непонятно все. Например не нашел в какой таблице хранятся ссылки на картинки записей в таблице wp_post не нашел толком ничего кроме заголовка и даты. Непонятно как в бд записи привязаны к рубрике. Помогите составить такой запрос.

P.S. данный запрос будет потом использован для получения из этих данных JSON и использования этого самого json в андроид приложении

Comment: Не надо лезть в базу руками. Пользуйтесь функциями WordPress. Там есть все необходимое.

Comment: А вообще, я так понимаю, что вам нужен просто ответ REST API WordPress. Почитайте вот это, например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/718391/220220 и это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/716351/220220 и документацию по rest api http://v2.wp-api.org/

Comment: Та документация устарела, вот новая https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример запроса к WordPress REST API, который возвращает все записи с номером категории 26:

```
http://test.kagg.eu/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=26
```

Введите эту строку в браузер, увидите ответ от моего тестового сайта.

REST API включен в состав последних версий WordPress, никаких плагинов устанавливать не нужно. Для изменения возвращаемой информации есть фильтры и действия WordPress, описанные в [документации](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/).

Так, для добавления картинки поста, следует добавить такой код в functions.php вашей темы:

```
function my_rest_prepare_post( $data, $post, $request ) {
    $_data                                 = $data->data;
    $thumbnail_id                          = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
    $thumbnail                             = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'full' );
    $_data['featured_image_thumbnail_url'] = $thumbnail[0];
    $data->data                            = $_data;

    return $data;
}

add_filter( 'rest_prepare_post', 'my_rest_prepare_post', 10, 3 );
```

Пример возвращаемой информации можно увидеть по ссылке выше.

Comment: Я разобрался в вашем примере. Установил плагин Rest API. и по вашему принципу получил готовый json из записей. Только вот я не нашел ссылок на картинки записей. Можно ли как-то их получить в этом json?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Да, действительно и без плагина работает. Видимо я не тот ID рубрики указывал. И картинка появилась. Спасибо большое.

Comment: А можно ли по такому же принципу получить в JSON только такую информацию: Дата создания, Заголовок, Текст и картинка. А то ссылка типа http://test.kagg.eu/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=26 выдает в json куча всего ненужного.

Comment: Можно, с помощью того самого фильтра, что в ответе. Сделайте unset ненужных ключей в массиве $data

Comment: А в полученном json есть массив content и в нем ключ respond где уже идет текст материала. В этом случае как сделать unset?

Comment: Сделайте var_dump($data) в фильтре, посмотрите на структуру массива. Или задайте новый вопрос, о том, как убрать ненужные поля из возвращаемого json